# Possible serialization error when executing Spark job from cluster with 1 master and 2 workers

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am executing Spark job on cluster. While it runs perfectly in a local mode, in the cluster it fails in the following line:

```
val labelsAndPredictions = testData.map(p => (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
```

I understand that the issue might be related to the fact that the object `model` is unaccessible for workers. Therefore I tried another approach. I created a serializable object `Utils` with two functions:

```
object Utils {

  var model: GradientBoostedTreesModel = null

  def loadModel(m: GradientBoostedTreesModel): Unit = {
    model = m
  }

  def makePrediction(features: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector): Double = {
    println(model.trees)
    val predictedLabel = model.predict(features)
    println("predictedLabel: " + predictedLabel)
    predictedLabel
  }

}
```

Then I substituted the prediction as follows:

```
  model = GradientBoostedTrees.train(trainingData, boostingStrategy)
  Utils.loadModel(model)

  val labelsAndPredictions = testData.map { x =>
    val prediction = Utils.makePrediction(x.features)
    (x.label, prediction)
  }
```

This is the command that I use to submit the Spark job:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g --num-executors 2 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch" --class org.test.Runner s3://mybucket/keys/trainer.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The utils object won't solve the problem because the model is initialised static to the driver, not workers.

The last time I checked (1.6.x) models are indeed not serializable.

What you can do is:

```
model.predict(testData.map(_.features))
```

But that won't provide you a nice way to assess the model without labels.

Or

```
testData.toLocalIterator.map { x => (x.label, model.predict(x.features)) }
```

toLocalIterator iterates the data in each partition, but on the driver rather than workers, giving you access to your model. Unfortunately not parallelised though.

Comment: What is the type of `testData`? In my case it's `RDD[LabeledPoint]` and when I try your second solution, `predict` is marked in red.

Comment: Also, does it make sense to try `mapPartitions` in order to make predictions on workers as well?

Comment: Edited. To answer you Q re: mappartitions, IIRC you don't want to do that because it still happens on the workers, but might be wrong.

Comment: .map { case(l,p) => l - p } gives you your prediction error, then try .tolist() and so on...

Comment: Thank you. Let me test it in the cluster. I will let you know if it worked.